# Allow only numeric values in textbox?

Tags: vb.net

I need to control the imputs of users in textbox so how I do that?
Thank you

Comment: A quick search should result in many suggestions of how to do this. Pick one and try it. If you have problems, post the details here and ask how to make it work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow user to enter only numbers in a textbox in vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413708/how-to-allow-user-to-enter-only-numbers-in-a-textbox-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
End If
```

Comment: Please what represent e.keychar=8 e.keychar between 48 and 57?

Comment: 8, 48 and 57 are the ASCII values. 8 is for 'Back Space' and 48 to 57 are for 0 to 9

So the code runs on KeyPress event. If the pressed key not BackSpace(You must allow user to use this key or user can't delete values) and if the 0 to 9 are entered then only the textBox will accept values.

Comment: You can add Error Message to the else part if needed. That will execute if user presses any other key than Backspace or 0 - 9.

Comment: Please mark it 'answered' if it works for you.

Comment: If I want to allow only arabic characters,how I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 13 AndAlso Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 AndAlso Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter numbers only")
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Already Asked same questions Here

[How to allow user to enter only numbers in a textbox in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413708/how-to-allow-user-to-enter-only-numbers-in-a-textbox-in-vb-net)

[Enter numeric value only into textbox in visual basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154449/enter-numeric-value-only-into-textbox-in-visual-basic)